# Jquery new Element Resulting in [object object] when concatenated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying create a new Anchor tag in Jquery with some attribute and storing it in variable, but when i concatenate it with other variable and append to Dom it gives [OBJECT OBJECT]

JsFiddle for the Same :
http://jsfiddle.net/T8q6T/

```
var a_name = "Sathwick Rao (sgmdev@gmail.com)^$^4083372345";
var _name = a_name.split('(')[0];
var _part1 = a_name.split('(')[1];
var _email = _part1.split(')')[0];
var htmlElement = $('<a>('+_email+')</a>').attr('href','mailto:'+_email);
$('#shara').html(_name+' '+htmlElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate a string with an object like that. Separate the two statements like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/E2Rur/

```
$('#shara').html(_name).append(htmlElement);
```

Comment: It's probably better to avoid 2 DOM reflows. Chaining DOM changing operations is quite a bad habit ;) Obviously this single case will not affect performance, however when it's part of a bigger application where this sort of approach is used many times, it could be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to concatenate an object with a string. Therefore, the object gets implicitly converted to it's string representation by it's `toString` function.

E.g.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
'some string' + div.toString(); //"some string[object HTMLDivElement]"
'some string' + div; //"some string[object HTMLDivElement]"
```

If you want to concatenate the `outerHTML` of the element with some other HTML string that is possible however.

```
$('#shara').html(_name + ' ' + htmlElement.prop('outerHTML'));
```

However it's not necessary the most optimal or *clean* way when it's not necessary.

```
$('#shara').append($('<span>').addClass('name').text(_name).add(htmlElement));
```

As you may have noticed, I `add` the `htmlElement` to the set and perform a single `append` operation rather than chaining two `append` calls. That's to avoid multiple DOM reflows, which are quite expensive.

If you do not want the wrapping `span` and use the same solution, you can also do:

```
$('#shara').append($(document.createTextNode(_name + ' ')).add(htmlElement));
```

Comment: @SJ-B Glad I could help. The other answer might be shorter, however it's causing two DOM reflows which is not as efficient. It's a good practice to avoid them as much as possible, even if you would probably not notice much difference in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

To force the variable `htmlElement` to store a string, I sometimes hack it like this

```
 var htmlElement = $('<a>('+_email+')</a>').attr('href','mailto:'+_email)+"";
 $('#shara').html(_name+' '+htmlElement);
```

Comment: That will produce the same undesired result. Please see my answer.